# In ggplot, using a numeric variable like a factor to create multiple plots, but using the numeric values to control spacing

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I make a data frame like this:

```
d1 <- data.frame(class=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=100),
                value=c(rnorm(100,0,1), rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1)))
```

I can easily make a violin plot with a separate violin for each class:

```
ggplot(d1, aes(x=class, y=value)) + geom_violin()
```

[image]

But if I make a data frame and plot like this, with numeric values:

```
d2 <- data.frame(timepoint=rep(c(1, 2, 3.5), each=100),
                 value=c(rnorm(100,0,1), rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1)))
ggplot(d2, aes(x=timepoint, y=value)) + geom_violin()
```

I just get a single violin plot like so:

[image]

I could do `factor(timepoint)`:

```
ggplot(d2, aes(x=factor(timepoint), y=value)) + geom_violin()
```

but then I get a plot with equal spacing. What I want is a plot where the third violin is farther to the right, since it is at time=3.5. That is, where the spacing reflects the actual values of `timepoint`.

[image]

I realize this isn't specific to violin plots, it could be a boxplot or any other kind of plot. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: add `group=timepoint` to your set of aesthetics, like `ggplot(d2, aes(x=timepoint, y=value, group=timepoint)) + geom_violin()`

Comment: Hey it works. Thanks. Make it an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested,

add `group=timepoint` to your set of aesthetics, like:

`ggplot(d2, aes(x=timepoint, y=value, group=timepoint)) + geom_violin()`